# Google Cloud permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a hosted server on Google Cloud Platform (GCP), and I am trying to overwrite some files.

I was able to make a connection through WinSCP, and I'm able to find the directory of the files I need to overwrite, however, all files are read-only.

How can I manage the permissions to give myself add/change permissions?

Answer (score 2):

I agree this seems to be related to permissions on the files. I am not able to comment and wanted to add that if you want to avoid changing the ownership of directory and files, you can always set up a group as an owner.

Details can be found on [this discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/184548/ftp-and-apache-permission-issues)

Summarizing:

```
# groupadd mygroup
# useradd -G mygroup user1
# chown -R :mygroup /path/folder
# chmod -R g+rw /path/folder
```

1. Create new group ‘mygroup’
2. Adds user user1 to mygroup
3. Recursively grants group ownership to content of /path/folder/ to mygroup
4. Recursively grants group read & write permission to contents of /path/folder
   This will effectively allow you to manage users in mygroup with the appropriate permissions and access.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be the owner of the file in order to be able to make changes. For example, if root is the owner of the file, you won't be able to change it (since GCP doesn't allow root access through FTP).

What you should do is make you (the user logged through WinSCP) owner of the file using command line and then make changes to the file. Be careful to make the old owner of the file owner again.

For example, using Centos and WinSCP you should do this:

> - Login to your server with WinSCP
> - Login to your server through putty or any other command line client
> - in putty: sudo chown YOUR_USER /complete/URL/file/in/your/server.XYZ
> - make whatever changes you need to make to your file
> - in putty: sudo chown OLD_USER /complete/URL/file/in/your/server.XYZ

YOUR_USER is the user you are logged in on WinSCP.

OLD_USER can be apache, root or whatever

If you want to upload a new file you must take ownership of the folder. To do that do not specify the file on the chown command, for instance:

> sudo chown YOUR_USER /complete/URL/folder/

Once you finish, give back ownership to OLD_USER.

This can be a pain but is the only way I found to edit my files in my GCP server...

Hope this helps.